# Partial SQL insert in haskelldb

Tags: sql, haskell

I just started a new project and wanted to use HaskellDB in the beginning. I created a database with 2 columns:

```
create table sensor (
    service text,
    name text
);
```

..found out how to do the basic HaskellDB machinery (ohhh..the documentation) and wanted to do an insert. However, I wanted to do a partial insert (there are supposed to be more columns), something like:

```
insert into sensor (service) values ('myservice');
```

Translated into HaskellDB:

```
transaction db $ insert db SE.sensor (SE.service <<- (Just $ senService sensor))
```

But...that simply doesn't work. What also does not work is if I specify the column names in different order, which is not exactly conenient as well. Is there a way to do a partial insert in haskelldb?

The error codes I get are - when I just inserted a different column (the 'name') as the first one:

```
Couldn't match expected type `SEI.Service'
       against inferred type `SEI.Name'
  Expected type: SEI.Intsensor
  Inferred type: Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                   SEI.Name (Expr String) er
When using functional dependencies to combine
  Database.HaskellDB.Query.InsertRec
    (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons f (e a) r)
    (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons f (Expr a) er),
etc..
```

And when I do the 'service' as the first - and only - field, I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                                SEI.Name
                                (Expr String)
                                (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                                   SEI.Time
                                   (Expr Int)
                                   (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                                      SEI.Intval (Expr Int) Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecNil))'
       against inferred type `Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecNil'
```

(I have a couple of other columns in the table)
This looks really like 'by design', unfortunately :(

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors you see, and the types calculated for some intermediate expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, that does look intentional.  The HaskellDB.Query docs show that `insert` has a type of:

```
insert :: (ToPrimExprs r, ShowRecRow r, InsertRec r er) => Database -> Table er -> Record r -> IO ()
```

In particular, the relation `InsertRec r er` must hold.  That's defined elsewhere by the recursive type program:

```
InsertRec RecNil RecNil
(InsertExpr e, InsertRec r er) => InsertRec (RecCons f (e a) r) (RecCons f (Expr a) er)
```

The first line is the base case.  The second line is an inductive case.  It really does want to walk every element of er, the table.  There's no short-circuit, and no support for re-ordering.  But in my own tests, I have seen this work, using `_default`:

```
insQ db = insert db test_tbl1 (c1 <<- (Just 5) # c2 << _default)
```

So if you want a partial insert, you can always say:

```
insC1 db x = insert db test_tbl1 (c1 <<- (Just x) # c2 << _default)
insC2 db x = insert db test_tbl2 (c1 << _default  # c2 <<- (Just x))
```

I realize this isn't everything you're looking for.  It looks like InsertRec can be re-written in the style of HList, to permit more generalization.  That would be an excellent contribution.